# New fragment within a camera activity at the same time - Android App

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity, camera

I want to display another activity within my camera activity like this [screenshot](http://www.uppic.com/uploads/14275942941.jpg), so that you can see two activities in one layout.

I have read [here](http://hmkcode.com/creating-android-fragment/) that I can use fragment to have two activities at the same time. But this doesn't work for me. How can I do it right?

I have two LinearLayout as you can see below in my camera layout.

camera_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
  ....some buttons that worked.
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/java_camera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="com.hmkcode.android.MyFragment"/>
</LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

> I can't add my fragment in camera_layout.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    class="com.hmkcode.android.MyFragment"/>
```

I become this error as I tried to add this fragment to my camera_layout.xml:

at moverio.imageprocess.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:116)

Without this is working faultless.

That happened in my "onCreate" method as I tried to use: setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);

This is my fragment_layout.xml (just an example, which i'm trying to use.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099ff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_A_TextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Fragment A"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment_A_Button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Click A" /> </LinearLayout>
```

MyFragment.java :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    return view;
} }
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: You can only have on Activity active at at time.  That tutorial you read stated that you can reuse fragments in multiple activities, it did not specifically say it, but it meant at different times.  Now, i think what you are trying to do is display multiple fragments in the same activity.  Based on your examples, I don't quite follow what you're doing nor know what your error is.  What is fragment_attitude?  Are you getting an error or just not seeing what you expect?

Comment: thanks for your response ... yes, I want to display multiple fragments in the same activity

Comment: sorry fragment_attitude was wrong ... I have edited. Please see my code again.